# Help understanding circuit for button example

Tags: arduino-uno, button, breadboard

I´m working on the button example
.Basically, i don't quite get the use of this connection.
[image]

Also, the breadboard i'm using is not quite the ones i see on most tutorials.
[image]

is there any 'mapping' i could make between them?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

The connection in that picture is pointless.  They are just putting power and ground on the top set of rails, but they aren't using it.

Your breadboard has only one rail on either side.  So you'll have to designate one for power and one for ground and you'll need some slightly longer wires for some of the connections.

Comment: Thank you! i get it now, i'll see if i can make it work.